# Using the selection margin and outlining region to select text in VS2010 beta 2

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Is it possible to get the selection margin and outlining region in VS2010 to work the way it does in VS2008 when you are trying to select a line of text with the mouse?

In 2010 you have to move an extra little way over to the left past the outlining region to select a line with the mouse, whereas in 2008 clicking in the outlining region also let you select the line.

In VS2010 dbl clicking in the outlining region on the gray line between the glyphs will expand/collapse the region but I'd prefer to be able to select the text instead..

Answer (score 0):

Seems so specific that i highly doubt that it would be a setting. So i guess not, but correct me if im wrong.